# AVCaptureSession captured photo's size different than the preview?

Tags: xamarin.ios, uiimage, calayer

[image: photo comparison]

EDIT:: Reading through this again now realize it isn’t very clear as to how the pictures were captured, how they’re being displayed, and why/what makes them different.

To that end— We are using AVCapture library to manually take photos within our app. We have a preview display in the app so the user can see what the image they’re taking looks like, just how any standard photo app these days does it. So what these two images are showing are the preview of the image on the screen, before the image is captured and the captured image. This was done by taking a screenshot of the preview and then a screenshot of the resulting capture image.

All this to say the captured image appears to be returned with differing dimensions or scaling attributes. We are displaying the preview and the resulting captures using a native iOS preview view and a Xamarin.Image respectively.

Below details our attempts at addressing the issue by changing sizing, layering, and stretching attributes to no avail.

To that end we’ve created a support ticket with MSFT regarding this issue.

These two images are the camera preview and the resulting capture (in that order, respectively [taken via screenshots]). We want the captured photo to match the preview/vice versa. How can we address this?

Tried manipulating the `CALayer` containing the photo data to size the image like how a Xamarin.Forms' image sizes with `AspectFit` by assigning the `ContentsGravity` with [various options](https://books.google.com/books?id=OUFsAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT31&lpg=PT31&dq=contentsgravity+strings&source=bl&ots=kTqw7zGF4t&sig=ACfU3U1pHm3vcbuboxwy__yl08BNkCm9yw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjyhZ3N64TqAhVYuZ4KHfnaDPAQ6AEwA3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=contentsgravity%20strings&f=false.) like `kCAGravityResizeAspect`. Fiddled with other `Contents` options such as `ContentsRect` and `ContentsScale` but no dice. Below is the `View` and its corresponding `Renderer`. So how to address the sizing issue?

Native Camera View

```
namespace App.iOS.Views
{
    public class NativeCameraView : UIView
    {
        AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer previewLayer;
        CameraOptions cameraOptions;

        public AVCaptureSession CaptureSession { get; private set; }

        public AVCaptureStillImageOutput CaptureOutput { get; set; }

        public bool IsPreviewing { get; set; }

        public NativeCameraPreview(CameraOptions options)
        {
            cameraOptions = options;
            IsPreviewing = false;
            Initialize();
        }

        public override void LayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.LayoutSubviews();

            UIDevice device = UIDevice.CurrentDevice;
            UIDeviceOrientation orientation = device.Orientation;
            AVCaptureConnection previewLayerConnection = this.previewLayer.Connection;
            if (previewLayerConnection.SupportsVideoOrientation)
            {
                switch (orientation)
                {
                    case UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait:
                        UpdatePreviewLayer(previewLayerConnection,
                            AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait);
                        break;
                    case UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight:
                        UpdatePreviewLayer(previewLayerConnection,
                            AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeLeft);
                        break;
                    case UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
                        UpdatePreviewLayer(previewLayerConnection,
                            AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeRight);
                        break;
                    case UIDeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown:
                        UpdatePreviewLayer(previewLayerConnection,
                            AVCaptureVideoOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown);
                        break;
                    default:
                        UpdatePreviewLayer(previewLayerConnection,
                            AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void UpdatePreviewLayer(AVCaptureConnection layer,
            AVCaptureVideoOrientation orientation)
        {
            layer.VideoOrientation = orientation;
            previewLayer.Frame = this.Bounds;
        }

        public async Task CapturePhoto()
        {
            var videoConnection = CaptureOutput.ConnectionFromMediaType(AVMediaType.Video);
            var sampleBuffer = await CaptureOutput.CaptureStillImageTaskAsync(videoConnection);
            var jpegData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.JpegStillToNSData(sampleBuffer);
            var photo = new UIImage(jpegData);
            var rotatedPhoto = RotateImage(photo, 180f);

            CALayer layer = new CALayer
            {
                //ContentsGravity = "kCAGravityResizeAspect",
                //ContentsRect = rect,
                //GeometryFlipped = true,
                ContentsScale = 1.0f,
                Frame = Bounds,
                Contents = rotatedPhoto.CGImage //Contents = photo.CGImage,
            };

            MainPage.UpdateSource(UIImageFromLayer(layer).AsJPEG().AsStream());
            MainPage.UpdateImage(UIImageFromLayer(layer).AsJPEG().AsStream());
        }

        public UIImage RotateImage(UIImage image, float degree)
        {
            float Radians = degree * (float)Math.PI / 180;

            UIView view = new UIView(frame: new CGRect(0, 0, image.Size.Width, image.Size.Height));
            CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation(Radians);
            view.Transform = t;
            CGSize size = view.Frame.Size;

            UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(size);
            CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();

            context.TranslateCTM(size.Width / 2, size.Height / 2);
            context.RotateCTM(Radians);
            context.ScaleCTM(1, -1);

            context.DrawImage(new CGRect(-image.Size.Width / 2, -image.Size.Height / 2, image.Size.Width, image.Size.Height), image.CGImage);

            UIImage imageCopy = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

            return imageCopy;
        }

        UIImage ImageFromLayer(CALayer layer)
        {
            UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(
                layer.Frame.Size,
                layer.Opaque,
                0);
            layer.RenderInContext(UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext());
            var outputImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
            return outputImage;
        }

        void Initialize()
        {
            CaptureSession = new AVCaptureSession();
            CaptureSession.SessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.PresetPhoto;
            previewLayer = new AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(CaptureSession)
            {
                Frame = Bounds,
                VideoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.ResizeAspectFill
            };

            var videoDevices = AVCaptureDevice.DevicesWithMediaType(AVMediaType.Video);
            var cameraPosition = (cameraOptions == CameraOptions.Front) ? AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front : AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back;
            var device = videoDevices.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Position == cameraPosition);

            if (device == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            NSError error;
            var input = new AVCaptureDeviceInput(device, out error);

            var dictionary = new NSMutableDictionary();
            dictionary[AVVideo.CodecKey] = new NSNumber((int)AVVideoCodec.JPEG);
            CaptureOutput = new AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
            {
                OutputSettings = new NSDictionary()
            };
            CaptureSession.AddOutput(CaptureOutput);

            CaptureSession.AddInput(input);
            Layer.AddSublayer(previewLayer);
            CaptureSession.StartRunning();
            IsPreviewing = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Native Camera Renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CameraView), typeof(CameraViewRenderer))]
namespace App.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class CameraViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CameraView, NativeCameraView>
    {
        NativeCameraView uiCameraView;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CameraView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                uiCameraView = new NativeCameraView(e.NewElement.Camera);
                SetNativeControl(uiCameraView);
            }
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                // Unsubscribe
                uiCameraView.Tapped -= OnCameraViewTapped;
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                // Subscribe
                uiCameraView.Tapped += OnCameraViewTapped;
            }
        }

        async void OnCameraViewTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await uiCameraView.CapturePhoto();
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE** A [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39350715/avcaptured-image-size-of-screen) question appears to have been asked quite some time ago.

Comment: I did some research and I found [AVCaptureStillImageOutput](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturestillimageoutput?language=objc) is deprecated and you can use [AVCapturePhotoOutput](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput?language=objc). You may config some settings there. Also, I found a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55150887/capture-photo-with-a-different-dimension-than-displayed) that may help.

Comment: @Jack Hua - MSFT Understood. Gave this a shot but didn’t get it working properly. Any C# implementation samples? I’ll let you know if we make any headway.

Comment: No, I don't have sample. You can share your solution here once you solve it:).

Comment: You can also open a free Xamarin [ticket](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6) for more help.

Comment: @Jack Hua - MSFT Tried that. Got this.. “ An error occurred while creating the support request.
cv:XXJioLxqiUaeozpj.107”

Comment: It should work, can you please try it again?

Comment: @Jack Hua - MSFT Done & done. Thanks for directing us there. Here’s hoping a solution is developed

Comment: Can you supply a MCVE (minimal, complete, verifiable example)? See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You are only showing the code on the native side, it would help to also see your CameraView class and the code for the page that is showing the CameraView.